How to make dynamic instance density in the viewport with geometry nodes?
I'm wondering if it's possible to make a scattering system with geometry nodes that would dynamically change the density of the viewport instances so that the total number of instances would stay the same or would increase logarithmically. As not to throttle the performance.
So when the "render" instance number would be low enough, it would show all of them, but when you would crank up the density, the viewport instances would (for example) increase logarithmically.
